# Logarithm of an operator

Tags: spectral-theory

For a positive operator $A$ we can write $A^{\alpha}=\frac{2\sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}w^{\alpha-1}(A+w)^{-1}Adw$ for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Is there a similar formula for $\log(A)$ where $A\ge 2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My recollection is that the notation $f(A)$, where $A$ is an operator and $f$ is some "nice" function (whatever is meant by "nice"), is understood via the [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus), which is essentially a restatement of the spectral theorem.  The book [*Functional Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rpFTTjxOYpsC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Reed and Simon is a reasonably approachable reference (see chapter VII).

Comment: chapter VII is not viewed can you please write an expanation as an aswer? thanks in avance

Comment: Honestly, I doubt that I can say much more than I have.  I haven't thought hard about the spectral theorem or its consequences in a long time, and I am by no means an expert.  If you don't have access to (a library with) Reed and Simon's text, you might consider Googling the phrases "functional calculus" and "spectral theorem."  Otherwise, you are going to have to hope that someone more knowledgable than myself comes along to answer your question.